# Отладка ошибок в асинхронном коде VSCode Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, отладка, asyncio, асинхронность

Я сделал намеренную ошибку *IndexError: list index out of range* в   **func1**.
Но программа не прерывается и не выводит ошибок, а асинхронный код продолжит работу второй функции **func2**.

Ошибка будет только, если убрать из **task** **func2**, чтобы была только одна функция **func1**.

```
import asyncio

arr = []
async def func1():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(3)
        print(arr[1])   # ERROR
        print('www')
 
async def func2():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        print('func2')

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()

task = [
    loop.create_task(func1()),
    loop.create_task(func2())
    ]
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(task))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, можно как-то в VSCode или ещё как отлаживать ошибки? Я ведь могу даже не подозревать о них.

Comment: В [документации asyncio.wait](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) вполне чётко написано, что он завершит свою работу только когда завершатся все таски (и там же написано, как изменить это поведение), и VSCode тут ни при чём

Comment: @andreymal Я добавил в wait: 
`return_when='FIRST_COMPLETED'`
 Спасибо большое!